# cochains valued in a central extension in terms of the cochains valued in the subgroup and the quotient.

Tags: finite-groups, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, group-extensions, topological-quantum-field-theory

Consider a finite abelian group $G$ and a subgroup $H\subset G$, and denote by $A=G/H$ the quotient. Then $G$ is an extension of $A$ by $H$ determined by the short exact sequence
$$
1\rightarrow H\rightarrow G\rightarrow A\rightarrow 1
$$
associated with a class in group cohomology $\epsilon \in H^2(B A, H)$. Thus $G$ is determined by $H,A$ and $\epsilon$. Now let $X$ be a simplicial topological space, and $a\in C^k(X,G)$ a $G$-valued k-cochain. Let us use additive notation for abelian groups. I would like to write $a$ uniquely in terms of a $H$-valued and an $A$-valued k-cochains $b\in C^k(X,H)$, $c\in C^k(X,A)$, using the datum $\epsilon \in H^2(BA, H)$.

Moreover I also need to write the differential $\delta a \in C^{k+1}(X,G)$ in terms of those of $b,c$.

I am pretty sure that this can be done but I don't know a clean and explicit way to do it. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homotopy cofiber sequence associated to $H→G→A$ is $$H→G→A→H[1]→G[1]→A[1]→⋯,$$
which induces a homotopy cofiber sequence of simplicial cochains $$\def\cC{{\sf C^*}}\cC(X,H)→\cC(X,G)→\cC(X,A)→\cC(X,H)[1]→\cC(X,G)[1]→\cC(X,A)[1]→⋯.$$

Thus, $\cC(X,G)$ is the homotopy fiber of the map $\cC(X,A)→\cC(X,H)[1]$.  The latter map can be written down concretely as the mapping cone of the map $\cC(X,G)→\cC(X,A)$.  This expands to yield precisely the desired description in terms of $A$-valued and $H$-valued cochains.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you wrote (but that's my fault, it sounds correct). I was looking for something a bit more explicit, so let me write what my guess was, please tell me if it could follow from your answer. If i denote by $\iota : H\rightarrow G$ the inclusion and by $s:A\rightarrow G$ a section, I would write 
$$
a=\iota (b)+s(c)
$$
and the differential as
$$
da=\iota (db+\beta(c))+s(dc)
$$
where $\beta(c)$ is the value of the Bockstein map associated with the sequence $H\rightarrow G\rightarrow A$. Is it correct?

Comment: @AndreaAntinucci: If G→A admits a section, then the extension is split, so there is no need to bother with ε in the first place.  The Bockstein map is induced by the cochain map $\def\cC{{\sf C^*}}\cC(X,A)→\cC(X,H)[1]$, so in principle the ingredients you wrote down are the right ones.

Comment: I don't want the extension to split, so that the section will not be an homomorphism. The failure to be an homomorphism is measured by the class determining the extension.

Comment: @AndreaAntinucci: If you write down the explicit formula for the mapping cocone (can be found, e.g., in Weibel's book) of the cochain map that induces the Bockstein homomorphism (also in Weibel's book), the resulting formula will be similar to yours (except, possibly, the signs).

Comment: Sorry could you provide the explicit reference for the things you are saying (I mean, like chapter, thm, def, etc.... in the book, which I guess is homological algebra)?

Comment: @AndreaAntinucci: Mapping cones as well as cofiber sequences are explained in Section 1.5 in Weibel's Homological Algebra.